# weighted moving average in pandas - having trouble implementing

Tags: python, pandas, moving-average, weighted-average

I have a one-dimensional time series (below), created using pandas. that I'm having trouble creating a weighted moving average for. I've seen others have come across this problem in pandas but there doesn't seem to be a consensus solution from what I've read.

```
1899    0.780
1900    -3.278
1901    1.096
1902    0.578
1903    4.608
1904    4.208
1905    -0.416
1906    1.392
1907    5.242
1908    2.922
1909    1.696
1910    2.984
1911    3.882
1912    0.536
1913    0.512
1914    0.170
1915    1.554
1916    3.936
1917    3.256
1918    1.404
... ...
```

The code I'm currently using is below, using weights (1-3-5-6-5-3-1), but I'm not getting accurate results. Any help would be appreciated.

```
wts = np.array([1, 3, 5, 6, 5, 3, 1])
def f(w):                        
         def g(x):
            return (w*x).mean()
        return g
anom_winter_av_npi.rolling(window=7).apply(f(wts))
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your weighted average function may be wrong (the code looks ok). Try:

```
# use the .dot method for shortness' sake
anom_winter_av_npi.rolling(window=7).apply(lambda x: wts.dot(x) / wts.sum())
```